# No method error issue rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm a new rails developer who has a basic scaffolded crud application that I modified a bit.

I'm getting this error:

`undefined method description for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102df26d8>`

when I visit `john/recipes/46`. Here's my view:

```
<h1 itemprop="name"><%= @recipe.name %></h1>
<ul>        
   <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_path(@recipe) %></li>
</ul>
<p itemprop="description"><%= @recipe.description %></p>
```

here's my routes:

```
match "/:username" => "recipes#index"
scope ':username' do
  resources :recipes
end
```

here's my show index:

```
def show
 @user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
 @recipe = Recipe.where(:user_recipe_id => params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @recipe }
 end
end
```

and my model:

```
before_save :set_next_user_recipe_id

belongs_to :users

validates :user_recipe_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}

def to_param
  self.user_recipe_id.to_s
end

def set_next_user_recipe_id
  self.user_recipe_id ||= get_new_user_recipe_id
end

def get_new_user_recipe_id
  user = self.user
  max = user.recipes.maximum('user_recipe_id') || 0
  max + 1
end

attr_accessible :description, :duration, :author, :url, :name, :yield, :ingredients_attributes, :user_recipe_id, :directions_attributes, :tag_list, :image
```

The reason I'm doing a `Recipe.where(:user_recipe_id => params[:id])` instead of `Recipe.where(:id => params[:id])` is because I'm trying to get so instead of `john/recipes/46` showing the 46th recipe in the database, instead to show the 46th recipe that belongs to John.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only trying to look for one recipe, but your query is searching for multiples. When you use a plain `where(...)` without ending it with `.first`, Rails interprets it as "show me **all** (multiple) Recipes with this user id" instead of "show me **the** (one) recipe with this id".

So you need to either put `.first` at the end of your query:

```
@recipe = Recipe.where(:user_recipe_id => params[:id]).first
```

or use an ActiveRecord finder that only returns one record:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find_by_user_recipe_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, when I do this I get `undefined method name for nil:NilClass?` What could this be from?

Comment: That would mean there was no recipe with the `user_recipe_id` provided.

Comment: please change your association table belongs_to :user. And when you want to show the name recipe using @recipe.user.name.